# QGIS print composer - Legend columns not aligning when title is deleted

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, printing

I want a simple legend without a title and with 2 items side by side. I can't find an option to turn the legend off so have just deleted text from the Legend title box. I select Columns (2) - Equal widths - Split layers.

What I get is misaligned entries (see attached).

I've tried changing the Title space to 0 and played around with the other spacing options but cannot get the writing to align.

[image]

Comment: I think your mistake is in the size of the symbols. Are they customized?

Comment: I think the first column is leaving a blank space/line for where the legend "Title" is supposed to go... if you add a title - although you don't want one - does it straighten things out at all?

Comment: Adding a title didn't help but playing with the size of the symbols did. The answer below also works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just create another legend item in your print layout and adjust them manually.

When you create your legend in the print layout with Add Item > Add Legend, on the right side of the print layout window, find item properties. Then scroll down to legend items and uncheck the auto update box.  Turn off all but "genetic sampling locations"
Example:
[image] 
After I uncheck auto update, I can remove stuff from the legend with the red minus button below. Here is the legend items box after removing all but one layer:
[image]

Now if you draw a legend on the print canvas, you'll only have the one item in it. 
Repeat the process, this time only include your "former range" layer. Now draw another legend on the print layout and you'll have something like this:

[image]

I highlighted both of them to prove the point that they are separate legend items on the print canvas. Now you can move them around until they are in alignment and look good on the final layout.

Comment: Thank you, good work-around. I also solved it but changing the size of the symbols which brought the text into alignment. However I think you're solution would be better in some circumstances when you wanted specific symbol size or shape.